# Clustering using CUES algorithm

Tags: java, data-mining, hierarchical-clustering

I am performing clustering of document using CUES algorithm. Based on the cluster distance, two clusters have to merged. When two clusters Ci and Cj are merged then, Ci is updated with Ci U Cj and Cj is removed and the index of clusters is updated.

I was initializing clusters using Set Class in Java. However, I am unable to update cluster at particular index. Please help me if there are any other classes that can be used. Please find algorithm below. Thank you.

```
 Input: a) A set of N clusters, C = {C1,C2, ...,CN} and noc = |C|, number of clusters.
 b) Ci = {di} ∀i ∈ N, where di is the ith document of the data set.
 c) A similarity matrix Sim[i][j] = cluster dis(Ci,Cj), ∀i, j ∈ [1,N].
 Steps of the Algorithm:
 1: X ← 0, Y ← 0
 2: while noc > 1 and X ≥ 0 and Y ≥ 0 do
 3:      min dist ← N
 4:      X ← −1, Y ← −1
 5:      for i = 1 to noc − 1 do
 6:         for j = i + 1 to noc do
 7:             if min dist ≥ cluster dis(Ci,Cj) and cluster dis(Ci,Cj) ≥ 0 then
 8:                   min dist ← cluster dis(Ci,Cj)
 9:                      X ← i, Y ← j
10:                 end if
11:             end for
12:           end for
13:          if X ≥ 0 and Y ≥ 0 then
14:                 CX ← CX ∪ CY
15:                 Sim ← merge(Sim, i, j)
16:               noc ← noc − 1
17:         end if
18: end while
19: return C
```

Comment: I see the algorithm, where is your Java code?  What are you having problems with specifically?

Comment: yes, can you share what you have done so far?

Comment: Looks like classig *hierarchical agglomerative clustering* to me... the oldest clustering algorithm, I guess.

Comment: In the above algorithm, we were not able to represent the cluster. We had used Sets. However while merging two clusters, we have to update one cluster with union and discard the second cluster.  Updating the HashSet in this case was difficult. Hence, now, we have defined a Cluster class to represent a cluster rather than using HashSet or HashMap.